# Twipsy data-trigger attribute and JQuery wierdness

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having trouble getting Twipsy to read the data attributes set on Twipsy-enabled element.

I have an `<input...>` control with the following attributes set:

```
rel="twipsy"
data-trigger="focus"
```

The  `<head...>` element contains the following JS script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
        $('[rel=twipsy]').twipsy({ live: true });
    });
});
```

When executed, Twipsy is triggered by the *mouseenter* and *mouseleave* events, not *focus* and *blur*, as the [documentation](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#twipsy) suggests.

So I changed the JS script on my page to:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
        $('[rel=twipsy]').twipsy({ live: true, trigger: ($(this).attr('data-trigger') == 'focus' ? 'focus' : 'hover') });
    });
});
```

Same result. Although I've been using Prototype for a long time, I only started playing with JQuery about a week ago, so it's entirely possible (OK - highly probable) that I simply don't understand how JQuery handles collections, enumeration and *this*.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
        $('[rel=twipsy]').each(function () {
            var trigger = $(this).attr('data-trigger')
            $(this).twipsy({ live: true, trigger: (trigger == 'focus' ? 'focus' : 'hover') })
        });
    });
});
```

And this works as expected.

So my question is this: What was I doing wrong in the first two examples? Why wasn't the data-trigger attribute of the  element being recognised and what was wrong with the JS script in the second example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second case:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
        $('[rel=twipsy]').twipsy({ live: true, trigger: ($(this).attr('data-trigger') == 'focus' ? 'focus' : 'hover') });
    });
});
```

You've used `$(this)` inside an anonymous function, it's pointing at the `document` object. You fixed it by putting the "work" inside of a `.each()` where jQuery was kind enough to set the context of `this` to what you had expected, your target. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c84DY/2/)

Your final solution is pretty much optimised. You are asking for a different action to be taken for each element of the matched set depending on some logic relating to its properties, so you are going to have to iterate over all of them in some way.The only change I would make is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('[rel=twipsy]').each(function () {
            var trigger = $(this).attr('data-trigger') === 'focus' ? 'focus' : 'hover')
            $(this).twipsy({ live: true, trigger: trigger })
        });
});
```

- ALWAYS use triple = when checking for strict equality
- The
  self-executing anonymous function was redundant
- Personally if I'm
  going to use a ternary for a switch case, I'd do it when saving the
  variable.

Comment: Thanks @Sinetheta. Would this be the correct way of handling it, or is there a shortcut way to 'bind' *this* to the correct context?

Comment: Yes, but JS only has "function context", even though you're making a chain with jQuery you're still inside whatever the last function was (in this case the document ready handler). If we were talking about an actual new function you could use "call" or "apply" to set the context http://devlicio.us/blogs/sergio_pereira/archive/2009/02/09/javascript-5-ways-to-call-a-function.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Twipsy is weird, I'll give you that.. but without even delving into  this too deeply, one thing I have to point out, for your sake, and and for anyone happening upon this post…

`$(document).ready(function () {`

and

`$(function () {`

ARE THE SAME THING!  Along with..

`jQuery(function () {` and `jQuery(document).ready(function () {`
and all their freaky friends.. But, "it" is bad enough once… don't *kill it* with it twice, lol.  I'm sure that can't be helping you out any..  Javascript is extremely anal.  Even one tiny mistake will make NOTHING work.  When in doubt, go back and look over EVERYTHING for dumb (and not-so-dumb) mistakes.